# Loading older google satellite image with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis-plugins, historical-imagery

I am using the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS. I want to use the google satellite layer, but there is a cloud on the specific image.

Is it possible to load one of the older google satellite images?

Like loading the older satellite images on google earth.

Comment: No. But try Bing satellite.

Answer (score 5):

No.  As far as I know, the OpenLayers plugin emulates a [web browser when downloading imagery tiles similar to googlemaps in a browser](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/tree/master/openlayers/html).  Therefore, only imagery available in googlemaps are available for display in QGIS via openlayers plugin.

The historical imagery in Google Earth is different.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think so. Thanks though