# Loading Historical Google Satellite Imagery with QGIS QuickMapServices plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-earth, historical-imagery

[Loading older google satellite image with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26616) is a similar question that was asked 4 years ago.

Is QGIS QuickMapServices able to load Google Earth's (aka Google Satellite's) historical imagery?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like the historical data is available through this method.

You can add more mapping services in the Quick Map Services plugin by going to Settings and then More Services. If you add the whole pack you get many more services, but not the Google one you want.

[image]

Comment: So there is no way currently to perhaps edit the QuickMapServices code that would add Google Earth's historical imaginary functionality?

Comment: I'm just an interested and keen user of the plugin, so I can't help you much there at all. But perhaps you can get in touch with the developer through their GitHub? https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices

Comment: ah so, good idea.... It is such a fantastic plugin! It will be interesting to ask the genius who created it and see if any WMS code modifications can be made to add the Google Earth historical aerials to the already amazing suite of layers available.

Comment: There seem to have been previous discussions along these lines that have come to no conclusion. Please report back with what happens (or perhaps we will see an update to the plugin)